# Multiple ManyToOne relationships in Doctrine

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, foreign-keys, entity-relationship

A simple issue, but I cant find any documentation for it.

I want to join one table to two other tables, on the same column with the same type of relationship. Pretty simple:

I have an Address table and a User table. Quite straight forward, one user can have many addresses:

**User.php**

```
/**
 * @OneToMany(targetEntity="Address", mappedBy="user", cascade={"persist", "remove"}) 
 */
private $addresses;
```

**Address.php**

```
/**
 * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="addresses") 
 */
private $user;
```

Now I want to add a new table which will also use Address (One supplier may have many addresses also).

**Supplier.php**

```
/**
 * @OneToMany(targetEntity="Address", mappedBy="**???**", cascade={"persist", "remove"}) 
 */
private $addresses;
```

Obviously I cant map by User, as that points from Address to User. I suppose I could add in another foreign key in the address table, but Im wondering if there is a better way to do this and continue using the same foreign key column for both User and Address.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only need to specify a `mappedBy` attribute when there is a bidirectional relationship to determine which side is the owning side.

From the docs:

http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/association-mapping.html#owning-side-and-inverse-side

> - A bidirectional relationship has both an owning side and an inverse side.
> - A unidirectional relationship only has an owning side.
> - The owning side of a relationship determines the updates to the relationship in the database.
>
> ...
>
> The following rules apply to bidirectional associations:
>
> The inverse side of a bidirectional relationship must refer to its
>   owning side by use of the mappedBy attribute of the OneToOne,
>   OneToMany, or ManyToMany mapping declaration. The mappedBy attribute
>   designates the field in the entity that is the owner of the
>   relationship.

In your case you only have unidirectional relationship which means you don't have to specify `mappedBy`, you may be able to leave it out.

---

Or you can add supplier to the Address class:

```
/**
 * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Supplier", inversedBy="addresses") 
 */
private $supplier;
```

which then allows you to set `mappedBy="supplier"` in `Supplier.php`

```
/**
 * @OneToMany(targetEntity="Address", mappedBy="supplier", cascade={"persist", "remove"}) 
 */
private $addresses;
```

Comment: I think the latter part of your answer will work, I was just half way through implementing it. I was trying to avoid this extra column, but I guess that would leave duplicate foreign keys in there, so looks like its going to be required.